# How to generate xml through serializing classes in case of nested xml

Tags: c#

my xml is below. i want to generate this same xml structure by using serialization.
so please guide me how to write the class which will generate this same type of xml structure at runtime. please help me with code. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<article id="97536" status="new">
    <analysis type="ALERT">
        <content>
            <header>
                <date>20071010</date>
                <hour>14:56</hour>
                <author>God</author>
                <media type="IMAGE"></media>
                <product>WIPS</product>
                <option>
                    <period_unit>day</period_unit>
                    <period_unit_count>1</period_unit_count>
                    <trend type="0020">0</trend>
                    <trend type="0050">0</trend>
                    <trend type="0020_50">0</trend>
                    <trend type="0101_SL">0</trend>
                    <trend type="0909_0">0</trend>
                    <volatility type="LITERS">1</volatility>
                    <momentum type="11170">0</momentum>
                    <momentum type="11130">0</momentum>
                    <strength type="VOLUME">0</strength>
                </option>
            </header>
        </content>
    </analysis>
</article>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like any xml i've ever seen. Can you post a properly formatted sample please.

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? Don't ask us to do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is as follows:

- Open the xml file in Visual Studio
- Generate a schema for the xml (XML->Create Schema)
- Tweak the schema for data types. Your date is for example not valid for a DateTime object
- Generate classes for the schema (xsd.exe filename.xsd /c)
- Include the generated .cs file in your project
- Deserialize your xml into your new classes